# How to create a clicking loop with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram

I'm building an Instagram bot, and I'm trying to get it to rapidly click through stories. I've found the element with Selenium:

```
next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'FhutL')]")))
```

I've already tried something myself, but I don't know how to set the conditions for a clicking loop to run, or what it should iterate through.

Here's the HTML of the button:

```
<button aria-label="Next" class="FhutL">
<div class="coreSpriteRightChevron"></div>
</button>
```

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: That class might be dynamic try //button[@aria-label='Next'] instead.

Comment: Also you can just use while True: try: #your code except: break so you can just click it everytime it comes up.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I like that one. Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a for loop coupled with wait for the expected condition that the item is clickable. See below:

EDIT: you have a small number of those you follow and want to handle no more storeis being available (an undetermined amount of looping).

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    
i=0
while i<1:
    try:
        NextStory = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'FhutL')]")))
        NextStory.click()
    except:
        i=1

#do the next thing...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. It is a quick and dirty solution though. It won't do more than a 100 stories, but when there's a number smaller than 100, it's still got to iterate all the way up to a 100. It is albeit really simple.

Comment: That's interesting...it doesn't show you stories non-stop?

Comment: @BikGer2 thanks for the feedback; does the new response better suite your needs?

Comment: Yeah, it works. I just used a while true loop with a try and except block. Thanks for the help!